# Ampere maxwell law and undefined derivative contradiction

Tags: electromagnetism

Applying the Ampere-Maxwell law for a point charge moving:

$$\nabla × \vec{B} = \mu_{0} \vec{J} + \mu_{0}\epsilon_{0} \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

Since differentiation at a point requires continuity, and at r=0 jefimenkos equation show that the electric field is not continuous nor defined, how can we even define dE/dt? How does a system of equations lead you to an answer, and then when checking their validity, leads you to be unable to substitute them in a consistent manner?

How can we define the curl of B when the right hand side is undefined? What am I missing?

Comment: "at $r=0$ jefimenkos equation show that the electric field is not continuous nor defined" How does Jefimenkos equation show that?

Comment: @jd27 by setting r=0 for the case of a distribution of the form $\rho = Q\delta^{3}(r)$

Answer (score 3):

Terms in this equation need not have finite value at position of the point charged particle, and some of them certainly don't ($\vec{J}$).

The equation term $\vec{J}$ becomes singular (of infinite magnitude) at that position. The equation still makes sense at all other points, which is often enough to make it useful. That is, the singularity at the particle does not prevent us from using this equation together with the other Maxwell's equations. If boundary conditions are added as well, we can find the electric and magnetic field as well (the Jefimenko formulae).

The term $\nabla\times\vec{B}$ is finite outside the particle, its magnitude increases when approaching the particle, and becomes of opposite direction and infinite in the particle.

The displacement current density

$$
\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}\nabla \times \vec{B} - \vec{J}
$$
is thus combination of two infinite quantities, and thus *could be* finite (two infinities cancelling each other), or it is undefined, or infinite.

We can study this problem using finite density of charge moving in some prescribed way and then try to find the limit of that when we continuously change the distribution into a point charge.

I did not do this calculation, but for an accelerated motion, due to EM self force effect analyzed by Lorentz and Abraham, which is infinite for point particle, electric field should come out infinite. So then displacement current density at the point particle is either undefined or infinite.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148564/discussion-on-answer-by-jan-lalinsky-ampere-maxwell-law-and-undefined-derivative); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.